# Is there a natural number $n$ such that $\underbrace{20182018 \cdots 20182018}_{n \text{ times}}$ is multiple of $2019.$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Is there  a natural number $n$ such that $\underbrace{20182018 \cdots 20182018}_{n \text{ times}}$ is multiple of $2019?$

Edit: This question was shown in a Math Competition and at first I thought it hasn't solution. Clearly I was wrong. I appreciate the effort from all of you. Thanks.

Comment: Use the pigeonhole principle .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A constructive proof:

$$2018\cdots2018=2018(1+10^4+10^8+\cdots+10^{4n})=2018\frac{10^{4n}-1}{999}$$

By Euler's theorem,  $10^{4\times336}=10^{1344}=10^{\phi(2019)}=2019k+1$  (since $10$ is coprime to $2019$), hence the LHS is divisible by $2019$.

However, $2019$ and $999$ have $3$ as greatest common divisor. So consider $$10^{4\times9072}=10^{\phi(27\times2019)}=27\times2019k+1$$ Thus $10^{4n}-1$ is divisible by $27\times2019$ and thus by $999\times 2019$ for at least $n=9072$.

---

This is not the least number for which $999\times2019$ divides $10^{4n}-1$.
Since $999\times2019=3^4\times37\times673$, it suffices to have $10^{4n}-1$ be divisible by each of these factors separately.
$10^3=1\pmod{37}$, $10^9=1\pmod{3^4}$, $10^{\phi(673)}=10^{672}=1\pmod{673}$. Combining these gives $10^{2016}=10^{4\times504}=1\pmod{2019\times999}$. So $504$ is the least such $n$.

Comment: Shouldn't you consider powers of 4?

Comment: Yes of course!  Amended.

Comment: $2019$ and $999$ aren't coprime, though. Both are divisible by $3$.

Answer (score 8):

The idea is to use the Pigeon Hole Principle.

Consider the set of integers

$$\{2018, 20182018, \ldots, \underbrace{2018\cdots2018}_{2020 \text{ times}}\}.$$

This set has $2020$ elements. If you consider the remainder that they leave when divided by $2019$, there are only $2019$ such numbers. Thus, two distinct elements of the above set must leave the same remainder. In other words, their difference must be divisible by $2019$.

Can you complete it now? (What must their difference look like?)

Comment: Their difference will have trailing zeroes, the problem statement does not mention that $2018\cdots20180\cdots 0$ are allowed...

Comment: @Sil: That is correct. The point then is to use the fact that $10$ is coprime to $2019$. In particular, if $2019$ divides $a\cdot10^n$, then $2019$ must divide $a$.